# Retrieving data from table

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

The WHERE clause in my query doesn't work as it should.
`SELECT * FROM Roeitijden WHERE ploegNaam = 'Test1'`
and it shows the row that contain 'Test1'
but whenever I put

```
SELECT * FROM Roeitijden WHERE ploegNaam = 'Heeren 1'
```

it doesn't view the row that contains 'Heeren 1'.

[When select works as it should](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEjTU.png)
[And this it the entire tabel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCAg7.png)

Comment: Probably there is a trailing space in `Heeren 1`. Try `WHERE TRIM(ploegNaam) = 'Heeren 1'`